# get all tag name on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I write a code to add click event to all tags in page with js.

```
function modifyText(obj) {
  console.log(obj.target.tagName);
}

var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
console.log(el);
for (var i=0 ;i<el.length; i++){
  el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
}
```

In `modifyText` function I wanna to get any tags that clicked on it.
for example in this html

```
<div>


  <h3>
    <b>salaaaaam<i> this is a test</i> </b>for add a click event to all tags in pages.
  </h3>

</div>
```

I wanna to print "I , B, H3 , DIV" when click on

> this is a test

but I get something like this "I ,I ,I ,I".

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/karimpazoki/1rch163p/5/)

can anybody help please?
Thanks.

Comment: use var el = document.querySelectorAll("*"); https://jsfiddle.net/1rch163p/6/

Comment: change `obj.target.tagName` to `this.tagName` - `this` would refer to the current element in the bubbling order whereas, `target` will always refer to the originating element.

Comment: No. That's different. @Endless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will refer to the element that actually triggered the event.

You can use `this` or [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to refer to the element to which the handler is bound.

```js
function modifyText(e) {
  snippet.log(this.tagName + ' || ' + e.currentTarget.tagName);
}

var el = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
console.log(el);
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener("click", modifyText, false);
}
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>
    <b>salaaaaam<i> this is a test</i> </b>for add a click event to all tags in pages.
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getTextNode(p) {
     p.onclick = function modifyText(obj) {
         console.log(obj.target.tagName);
     }
     var childArr = p.childNodes;
     for (var i = 0; i < childArr.length; i++) {
         textNodeArr = getTextNode(childArr[i]);
     }
     return;
 }

 arr = getTextNode(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a listener to all element is quite expensive and wouldn't work for newly added elements
What i would do is add one listener on top and go from there

```
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    var elm = evt.target
    var els = []
    while (elm.tagName) {
        els.push(elm.tagName)
        elm = elm.parentNode
    }
    alert(els)
}, false)
```